# Where can I get a list of all of the Robotium commands?

Tags: android, automation, robotium

Where can I get all Robotium commands?

(`*waitForView*, *appBar*, clickExit*`... all of them)

I searched the web and couldn't find a complete listing anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just download it. Here is javadoc:
http://code.google.com/p/robotium/downloads/list

Edit, actual javadoc is under: http://recorder.robotium.com/javadoc/

Answer (score 0):

UTSL: https://github.com/jayway/robotium/tree/master/robotium-solo/src/main/java/com/jayway/android/robotium/solo

Just clone it, then generate the javadocs if you must.